Change Msix family package name?

I'm trying to update my microsoft store app and I keep getting this error. Does anyone know how to edit the package family name in a flutter project on android studio? Also, my CN= is the same in my pubsec and in the information of my app on the store.

When delivered via the Store, the certificate's Subject is actually a GUID (basically your Store ID); you cannot change this to your preferred CN=... string. You can see this by locating your installed app on the system, then right-clicking on AppxSignature.p7x and looking at the Digital Signatures tab.
For example, the Subject for the "Spotify" App Package is:

CN = 453637B3-4E12-4CDF-B0D3-2A3C863BF6EF

even though the Subject on the certificate used to sign Spotify.exe inside the package is:

CN = Spotify AB, O = Spotify AB, L = Stockholm, ...

Usually Visual Studio will make sure this matches after you link your app to the Store listing.
